# Go requires comma, when put there, other unrelated errors are thrown

Tags: go, reddit

I'm trying to create a reddit bot in Golang using [this](https://github.com/turnage/graw/) library, and Golang is asking for a comma, however, when I put it there, Go throws other errors.

Here's my main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
  "github.com/turnage/graw/reddit"
)

func main() {
  cfg := BotConfig{
    Agent: "graw:doc_demo_bot:0.3.1 by /u/yourusername",
    // Your registered app info from following:
    // https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2
    App: App{
      ID:     "sdf09ofnsdf",
      Secret: "skldjnfksjdnf",
      Username: "yourbotusername",
      Password: "yourbotspassword",
    }
  }
  bot, _ := NewBot(cfg)
  bot.SendMessage("roxven", "Thanks for making this Reddit API!", "It's ok.")
}
```

Here's the output with the code above (no comma at 17:7):

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:17:6: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or }
```

Here's the output when I put the comma there:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:4:3: imported and not used: "github.com/turnage/graw/reddit"
./main.go:8:10: undefined: BotConfig
./main.go:19:13: undefined: NewBot
```

I've also tried putting a comma after line 16 (so that there are two) and I get this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:16:36: syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting expression
./main.go:17:6: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Which line is 17?

Comment: Right below the password line

Comment: The accepted answer didn't address your original question about commas and the confusion about how adding commas or removing exposes seemingly different error messages.

Comment: Correct, however my issue wasn't actually with the commas-- it did need a comma at line 17. The issue was actually my malformed input, I just didn't realise that at the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors (after fixing the syntax issue by adding the comma) are all related to each other.  As written, you *aren't* using the package you've imported.  Use `reddit.BotConfig`, `reddit.App`, and `reddit.NewBot` to use the structs and functions from that package.  Importing in Go doesn't bring things into a global top-level namespace.

```
func main() {
    cfg := reddit.BotConfig{
        Agent: "graw:doc_demo_bot:0.3.1 by /u/yourusername",
        // Your registered app info from following:
        // https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2
        App: reddit.App{
            ID:       "sdf09ofnsdf",
            Secret:   "skldjnfksjdnf",
            Username: "yourbotusername",
            Password: "yourbotspassword",
        },
    }
    bot, _ := reddit.NewBot(cfg)
    bot.SendMessage("roxven", "Thanks for making this Reddit API!", "It's ok.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fine to put a `,` after

```
App: App{
  ID:     "sdf09ofnsdf",
  Secret: "skldjnfksjdnf",
  Username: "yourbotusername",
  Password: "yourbotspassword",
}, //like this
```

The other errors are actually the errors that you will need to fix. Golang is strict and will not allow unused imports or unused variables. Also, you have to import packages that contain the definitions of the structs that you use - `BotConfig` and `NewBot`.

You can name your imports so you can refer to your imports without having to do `reddit.BotConfig`. For ex

```
import r "github.com/turnage/graw/reddit"
```

This will allow you to simply use `r.BotConfig` for ex. Otherwise for each time you want to use BotConfig you'll have to refer to the package name as `reddit.BotConfig`